# Using jq to get key and value from JSON

Tags: json, bash, jq

Here's a single (of many, prettified) JSON object returned by `curl <url> | jq '.'`

```
{
 "63": {
    "state": {
      "on": false,
      "alert": "select",
      "mode": "automation",
      "reachable": true
    },
    "swupdate": {
      "state": "notupdatable",
      "lastinstall": "2019-09-15T11:19:15"
    },
    "type": "plug",
    "name": "Tree",
    "modelid": "XXX",
    "manufacturername": "XXX",
    "productname": "plug",
    "capabilities": {
      "certified": false,
      "control": {},
      "streaming": {
        "renderer": false,
        "proxy": false
      }
    },
    "config": {
      "archetype": "plug",
      "function": "functional",
      "direction": "omnidirectional"
    },
    "uniqueid": "00:0d:6f:ff:fe:da:c9:dc-01",
    "swversion": "2.0.022"
  }
}
```

I want to pipe the output to `jq` so that I can return the key and name from each object, e.g. "63" "Tree" (I am not concerned if the result is in parentheses or how the fields are separated or whether "name": is included.)

I can get keys:
`curl <url> | jq -r 'keys[]'`

and names:
`curl <url> \ jq -r '.[]{"name"}`

but I can't get them both on the same line.

Comment: Thanks. Looks interesting, but I do want to get my head around jq first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A succinct, efficient, and some would say elegant, solution:

```
map_values(.name)
```

One of many alternatives:

```
with_entries( {key, value: .value.name} )
```

If you want everything on a single line, you could use the -c command-line option.

Comment: That does do what I want. Thank you. If I wanted to extend it to include state.reachable value, could I do that using the same solution?

Comment: Yes, both `map_values` and `with_entries` are very powerful. It will probably be worth your while to understand how to use them.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at them both. I'd struggled with understanding jq (in case you couldn't tell) so I appreciate your help.